# Is it possible to spoof current time from devtools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge

I need to spoof current time to test my frontend code. Is it possible to do in the devtools?

Comment: I agree with the comment above, you can also refer to [this blog](https://dev.to/aileenr/how-to-spoof-your-timezone-in-google-chrome-48ch).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you! Unfortunately there's nothing to spoof current time other then change system time and restart the browser. But at least I have a way to change timezone.

Comment: Maybe there's a chrome extension to spoof the time.